# How to search Punjabi regional language keyword in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, full-text-search

i am getting different result when running query using PHPMyAdmin and using PHP script.

It is our regional language Punjabi keyword **ਹਰਪ੍ਰੀਤ ਕੌਰ ਪਟਿਆਲਾ**

I am executing below MySql query using PHPMyAdmin

```
select * from postinfo where match(info) against('ਹਰਪ੍ਰੀਤ ਕੌਰ ਪਟਿਆਲਾ')
```

Giving me accurate result.

[image]

But when running same Query using PHP form Search

**Code:**

```
$name=trim($_POST['name']);
$sql="select * from postinfo where match(info) against('$name') LIMIT 10";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Then the result is blank.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you print `$name` or `$sql` to look at the assembled query before calling `mysql_query()`? Try that and show us the results. Perhaps the problem is your POST data.

Comment: $name returning ਹਰਪ੍ਰੀਤ ਕੌਰ ਪਟਿਆਲਾ 
and 
$sql returning 

select * from postinfo where match(info) against('ਹਰਪ੍ਰੀਤ ਕੌਰ ਪਟਿਆਲਾ') LIMIT 10

Comment: Hm, looks okay; are you checking for errors back from MySQL along the way? For example, when I'm running mysql_query() I do so with a call like `$result = mysql_query($query, $dbconn) or die ('Query failed! ' . mysql_error());`.